# In MVP pattern, which layer should check internet connection?

Tags: android, android-mvp

In android, while implementing MVP pattern, which layer should check internet connection? Model, View or Presenter?

Comment: IMHO, none of the above. Data access should be handled by your data layer, such as a repository or a data source. That includes providing details about the availability of the data, such as whether you can communicate with the server.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am new in MVP. For checking connection, Context, ConnectivityManager & NetworkInfo are needed. Can you tell me, where to put this logic?

Comment: As @CommonsWare said; Put it into another package which will have all the responsibilities regarding data. Any responsibility regarding data like accessing data, converting fetched data from the network into appropriate data model class, persisting fetched data into a local cache or local DB, syncing the app data with cloud backup etc.

Comment: imagine this flow: VIEW -- (input event) ---> PRESENTER --- (provide data) --> MODEL --- (data spec) ---> REPOSITORY -- (request data) --> DATA (get data - local db, api etc or error).  It is suggested that this logic and responsibility lies in the repository or data layer.

Comment: Just expose it from a BehaviorRelay from your Application class globally.

Answer (score 1):

[source](https://medium.com/cr8resume/make-you-hand-dirty-with-mvp-model-view-presenter-eab5b5c16e42)

The model uses the resources to check the connection. they are not part of the model though...

Model
In an application with a good layered architecture, this model would only be the gateway to the domain layer or business logic. See it as the provider of the data we want to display in the view. Model’s responsibilities include using APIs, caching data, managing databases and so on.

View
The View, usually implemented by an Activity, will contain a reference to the presenter. The only thing that the view will do is to call a method from the Presenter every time there is an interface action.

Presenter
The Presenter is responsible to act as the middle man between View and Model. It retrieves data from the Model and returns it formatted to the View. But unlike the typical MVC, it also decides what happens when you interact with the View.